# php how include and run method from php file where is html code?

Tags: php

I wrote my index.php file, its this:

```
<?php  // index.php
 if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) {
  header("location: profile.php");
 }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Bejelentkezés</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
  <div>
   <h1>Wellis adatok</h1>
   <div>
    <h2>Bejelentkezés</h2>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
     <label>Felhasználó neve :</label>
     <input id="name" name="userName" placeholder="név" type="text"></br></br>
     <label>Jelszó :</label>
     <input id="password" name="password" placeholder="**********" type="password" style="width: 80px"></br></br>
     <input name="submit" type="submit" value="   Login   ">
     <span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <p>
   </br>
   Listák megtekintése:
   <?php
    include("functions.php");
    welcome();
   ?>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Also there is an other: functions.php, where are lots of functions. One of those is this:

```
<?php // functions.php

 function welcome() {
  echo "Welcome here ...";
 }

...

?>
```

I wanna run that welcome() method there. This is only sample but orhers are same like this. I wanna see welcome message below login fields and submit button.
The page is hungarian but the page works well except this probleme.

Thanks for quick help ...

Comment: i cannot see error, it should work fine.

Comment: That is problem, becouse me don't work.
Do you see welcome message below the fields?

Comment: Its okey me too.